# Riddle with seven - or is it eight?

Tags: riddle, knowledge, literature

Here's another riddle on the theme of literature.

> I am the oldest, and take care of the monsters.
>
> My first is a loner, but has a few children.
>
> My second is a lion, lover of wealth.
>
> My third was the black sheep of the family.
>
> My fourth, fifth, and sixth might be Taurus, Nagini, and Dracula.
>
> My seventh is a bear, found in the north.
>
> Then there's the eighth, the newest and one day the greatest. Coming out of nowhere, as it seemed, to supplant the black sheep and perhaps all the rest. Innocence, wisdom, and strength all run errands for this one.

**Who am I (the speaker)?**

HINT:

> [A recipe for lemon tea stew](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/15420/5373)

Comment: Nagini :)!!  Hooray!

Comment: Maybe something from HoO?

Comment: Sun??? and the eight planets??

Comment: @AJL I don't know what HoO stands for, so the answer must be no!

Comment: @ArghyaChakraborty Nope, 'fraid not.

Comment: Could this be about... very old literature?

Comment: Sorry, HoO as in Heroes of Olympus...  Prophecy of seven etc.

Comment: Any chance it's something to do with A Song of Ice and Fire? I'm working from vague memory from when I read Game of Thrones, but isn't the northern family's symbol the bear? EDIT: Apparently, it's a lion. So maybe not. But I suspect it's something like that (that is, another classic Fantasy book)

Comment: Dunno why but it got me thinking of the Weasley family from the HP books. Doesn't fit  (or can't make it fit) though.

Comment: @GlenO The northern family's symbol is a *wolf* - but no, it's nothing to do with aSoIaF. You're on the right lines though!

Comment: I felt like this riddle really deserved answer attempts. So I came up with one :P

Comment: @Spacemonkey Thanks! I don't know anything about Pokemon, but I think you were closer (though still quite a long way off) with HP.

Comment: Kind of fits constellations too except for the speaker and the 8th. : /

Comment: I've now upvoted the comments (from @AJL, Glen O, and Spacemonkey) which are currently closest to the correct answer.

Comment: Rand.. I wish there was a way to PM you about this.

Comment: lol, Same here, I keep coming up with a new trivia answer/idea but constantly end up finding a couple of the clues don't fit properly. Latest being one that just inspired me to create my own trivia riddle :P

Comment: I don't know *who* you are, but I think I know *what* you are: A writer.

Comment: **Chatroom for this puzzle now open [here](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/24004/chat-about-a-puzzle).** I'll check in every so often; feel free to ask questions or speculate.

Comment: @Spacemonkey Yep... just read that one :) And yours inspired rand to write another?!?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The book(s):

> The Belgariad, a five book series as well as The Malloreon, the five book sequel to the Belgariad

The one who takes care of the monsters is

> UL, god of Ulgos and monsters

First is

> Aldur, who took disciples instead of having a people

The second is

> Nedra, lion god

The third is

> Torak, only to take a monster as his totem

The fourth is

> Chaldan, bull god

The fifth is

> Issa, snake god

The sixth is

> Mara, bat god

The seventh is

> Belar, bear god

The eighth is(spoiler!!!)

> Eriond, who took over for Torak after he was killed.  It was said he would become god of all other races.

Comment: Nice work! Maybe you could mention the book series (and don't forget the other five!) at the top of your answer instead of the bottom? Also a spoiler warning would be good. I realised after writing this riddle that the bit about the "eighth" would be a massive spoiler for anyone who hadn't read the Malloreon!

Comment: Ok, sorry...  I didn't really realize..

Comment: Ok well all is good, never actually ever even heard of the book. Now I can rest easy (and read up one what this book is and if I should read it after I finish the last 4 books of the WoT)

Comment: @Spacemonkey I think it's worth reading, although nowhere near the quality of WoT. The geography and characters in particular are very well-imagined, even if the latter can be a bit caricaturised.

Answer (score 1):

(Disclaimer: Okay, I don't think this is the answer because it's like cheating, I can make whatever I want fit - I googled 95% of them. But I found it funny.)

Clearly you are:

> A pokemon master!

The loner is :

> Cubone - chillin' in his tower

The lion is: (Take your pick)

> ?Entei, Luxray, Litleo etc...

The Black Sheep is:

> Mareep?

Taurus, Nagini, and Dracula:

> Tauros, Arbok, Crobat

The bear is:

> Snorlax

The newest are from what I gather, generally OP'ed so.... just choose which ever you want. Back in my days it was:

> Mew and Mewtwo

Comment: Nope, way off I'm afraid. All those question marks are a bad sign ;-) And in case people see this answer and think my riddle is too broad, let me just say that "I can make whatever I want fit" is wrong: there's a unique answer which will make perfect sense when you get it!

Comment: I meant I can choose whichever pokemon thingy to make it fit, not any answer can fit. :P