# A recipe for lemon tea stew

Tags: riddle, enigmatic-puzzle

Here's an old recipe I found in my tower for **lemon tea stew**.

### Ingredients

6 cups of tea
4 eggs
2 eyeballs<sup>1</sup>
2 leeks
4 lemons
1 banana
2 chicken wings
several dates
about half an onion

<sub><sup>1</sup> Or fake jelly eyeballs for the squeamish.</sub>

### Instructions

Take a nice cup of tea,
Left to age well,
And mix in the first egg.

Double your portions of everything,
Toss in an eyeball for the witch,
Then the first leek, well chopped,
Simmer, and add the first lemon.

Throw in half a banana,
The roasted wing of a hen,
And add the first few dates.

Another cup of tea,
Having been left to age,
And the second lemon.

Double your portions all over again,
Chop nearly half of an onion,
And, after first roasting well,
Finally you have your food.

---

If you put it all together the way it's supposed to be done, what do you get?

Comment: I'm guessing it's not a lemon tea stew.

Comment: Maybe it's a French mountain? Le Mont Eastew?

Comment: @IanMacDonald Nah, "lemon tea stew" is just something I came up with when looking for a descriptive title.

Comment: @rand al'thor I think you should stay away from Nynaeve's tea recipes.

Comment: Does this recipe require any mixing? Or are we just layering ingredients up in order?

Comment: Is it McDonald's burger?

Comment: @Alconja: Just in order. Leoll2: nope. Spacemonkey: hilarious! :-)

Comment: (I left a comment on Avon's now-deleted answer, which I'm copying here so that everyone can see even if they don't have enough rep to see deleted answers.) Note that the ingredients can all be deduced from the instructions, so the instructions are enough to solve the puzzle.

Comment: I never was much of a cook... I think I must've used the wrong setting on the stove: "The the ill and a the the the ill and a then".

Comment: @Alconja You're misinterpreting the "double your portions" bit, and I can't see where that "then" comes from, but otherwise looking good!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

<sub>I should've realised, given that it was rand al'thor asking the question, that it would relate to a fantasy novel... :)</sub>

Making this lemon tea stew will get you:

> The Will and the Word (the term use for sorcery in [the fantasy series, The Belgariad](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Belgariad))

**Nutrition information**:

> Take a nice cup of tea, => **T**
>  Left to age well, => **H** (sounds like "age")
>  And mix in the first egg. => **E** ("first" letter of "egg")
>
>  Double your portions of everything, => **W** ("double you[r]")
>  Toss in an eyeball for the witch, => **I** ("eye")
>  Then the first leek, well chopped, => **L** ("first" of "leek")
>  Simmer, and add the first lemon. => **L** ("first" of "lemon")
>
>  Throw in half a banana, => **A** (bAnAnA, A is half of the letters)
>  The roasted wing of a hen, => **N** ("wings" of "hen" are "h" and "n"... we'll just grab one)
>  And add the first few dates. => **D** ("first" of "dates")
>
>  Another cup of tea, => **T**
>  Having been left to age, => **H**
>  And the second lemon. => **E** ("second" letter of "lemon")
>
>  Double your portions all over again, => **W**
>  Chop nearly half of an onion, => **O** (OniOn, O is almost half of the letters)
>  And, after first roasting well, => **R** ("first" of "roasting")
>  Finally you have your food. => **D** ("final" of "food")

Comment: Very nice job! I like your interpretation of "wing of a hen", but all I really meant was that "hen" sounds like N. "Onion" was the really ambiguous one (which I didn't realise when making the puzzle), but luckily WORD makes more sense than WNRD...

Comment: And _I_ should've realised this riddle wouldn't last long with an expert solver like you around :-)